# How to handle LocaleDateTime backend response in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a table row as

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="date">
          <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef fxFlex="10%">Date</mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let payroll"
                    fxFlex="10%"> {{payroll.creationDateTime}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

And here i want to show the date in logical format but the response coming from backend is :

```
{
"id": 5,
"employeeId": 42198,
"budgetGroupId": 15541,
"creationDateTime": {
"year": 2018,
"month": "MARCH",
"monthValue": 3,
"dayOfMonth": 1,
"dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
"dayOfYear": 60,
"hour": 19,
"minute": 24,
"second": 3,
"nano": 190000000,
"chronology": {
"id": "ISO",
"calendarType": "iso8601"
}
}
}
```

How can i take that creationDateTime from there in a good format without taking all its inner values one by one and concat?

Comment: In which format you want to show the date ?

Comment: Maybe it's better to stringify the date on your backend so that it's easily consumable by frontend as well as no unnecessary data going across network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use overfload of `Date` object. The overload can be seen at [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [,
>   milliseconds]]]]]);

```js
let dateObject = {
    "id": 5,
    "employeeId": 42198,
    "budgetGroupId": 15541,
    "creationDateTime": {
        "year": 2018,
        "month": "MARCH",
        "monthValue": 3,
        "dayOfMonth": 1,
        "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
        "dayOfYear": 60,
        "hour": 19,
        "minute": 24,
        "second": 3,
        "nano": 190000000,
        "chronology": {
            "id": "ISO",
            "calendarType": "iso8601"
        }
    }
};

var date = new Date(dateObject.creationDateTime.year, 
   dateObject.creationDateTime.monthValue - 1, 
   dateObject.creationDateTime.dayOfMonth,
   dateObject.creationDateTime.hour, 
   dateObject.creationDateTime.minute, 
   dateObject.creationDateTime.second);
console.log(date);
```